# Google datastore Java SDK wont authenticate on Windows 10 - Works fine on OS X

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I run my springboot app that communicates with Google Cloud Datastore via the the Java SDK I get the following error:

```
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Unexpected OK error code with HTTP status code of 401. Message: .
```

However this only happens on Windows machines, on two OS X devices the code works fine. I have installed the Google Cloud SDK on all my machines and logged in successfully. In my code I am just getting the default credentials:

```
DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

So I am at a loss, seemingly performing the same setup steps on OS X and Windows 10 yield different result RE authentication against Google Cloud resources!

Comment: Are you using environment variables? Check if they're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like on Windows you have to run:  gcloud auth application-default login as an admin on the command line. I did not have to do this on OS X